# ROS Answers SE migration: qt app and ros

Tags: qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am making an application by Qt to control my robot ,but  I have no ideas.
And here is what I want to do in this application:

1.make a teleoperation gui to control my robot;
2.display laser scan map from my robot in this gui;
3.display the pose message of my robot in this gui;
4.and there is a usb_camera on my robot , so I want to display the picture from it;

So can anybody give me some advise?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203566/qt-app-and-ros/) by [Anthony Brooks](https://answers.ros.org/users/21690/anthony-brooks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-02-23**:
Do you want to have this application or do you want to make that? Because most/all of this functionality already exists in ROS.

**Comment by [Anthony Brooks](https://answers.ros.org/users/21690/anthony-brooks/) on 2015-02-23**:
Thanks for your  reply.
And , I know that all of these already exist in ROS, but I want to make all of these in one application made by Qt,but I have no ideas  how to do this . So can you give me some advise more detailed?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-02-23**:
Are you aware that rqt lets you loading plugins into one rqt instance?

**Comment by [Anthony Brooks](https://answers.ros.org/users/21690/anthony-brooks/) on 2015-02-23**:
Thank you , I have awared this just now , but I also would like to know : are there some plugins in rqt that could get the laser scanning map and display it in real-time ? (not rviz) So can you give me some advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In addition to @dornhege's comment, you can also create your own rqt plugin by reusing existing rqt plugins. [This QA](http://answers.ros.org/question/200876/rqt-custom-imageview-showing-images-from-different-cameras/) might be of your help.

For laser, it depends on how you want to visualize laser input. [RViz has LaserScan](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/LaserScan) FYI.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anthony Brooks](https://answers.ros.org/users/21690/anthony-brooks/) on 2015-02-24**:
Thanks for your reply , I will just try your advise.